# Cannot round corners of labels in a Custom Collection View Cell in iOSSwift

Tags: ios, collectionview

Please can you help out with a query. I am using Xcode (11.5), iOS Single Page App. I have built a custom collection view cell that displays an image, label and button.

In the custom cell class, I have a function that updates the layer properties of the objects e.g.

```
button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
label.layer.cornerRadius = 5.
```

When I run the code, only the button's corners are rounded. The label's corner doesn't get update. I can change the background color of the label but not the corner radius.

Also the `borderWidth` as well for the label doesn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'label.layer.masksToBounds = true'

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a reason why this has to be done for labels and not buttons or imageviews?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `label.clipToBounds = true`

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Is there a reason why this has to be done for labels and not buttons or imageviews?

Comment: it depends on class's implementation:
for example, in UIButton's implementation, I can change `clipToBounds = true`. And in UILabel I can change `clipToBounds = false`. So you should check it by yourself or always set it to true when use border.